# D3 - How can I put an SVG into a DIV via a function?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, observablehq

To reuse code I want to put my SVG into a function and call it as needed. Once I select the DIV what is the appropriate construct to render the SVG inside it?

```
...

if (intLocations.includes(comm.location)) {
  const intActivities = d3.select('div#intActivities')
  intActivities.append(Pill(comm))
} else {
  const extActivities = d3.select('div#extActivities')
  actActivities.append(Pill(comm))
}

...

function Pill(comm) {
   const svgNode = d3.create('svg')
   svgNode
       .attr('width', 100)
       .attr('height', 100)
       .append('g')
       // More code to draw the figure using comm data.
   return svgNode;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`intActivities.append(() => Pill(comm).node())` should do the trick. Here's an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="my-div"></div>

  <script>
    d3.select('#my-div').append(() => square().node());

    function square() {
      const svg = d3.create('svg')
          .attr('width', 100)
          .attr('height', 100);

      svg.append('rect')
          .attr('width', 100)
          .attr('height', 100)
          .attr('fill', 'navy');

      return svg;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Alternatively, you could pass your `Pill` function the div selection that you want to add it to.